# Extracting parent and child information

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

Using Python and beautifulsoup, I need help extracting information from a parent div and a child div at the same time.

Here is the first example code:

```
<div id="slide-609becd056bb40a7ad42607a4d1c67f5" 
class="slide has-link slick-slide" 
data-label="April 2 2018 Acura TLX Offer 2000x700.jpg" 
data-link="/new-inventory/index.htm?model=TLX&amp;year=2018" data-target="_self" 
style="background-image: url(&quot;https://pictures.dealer.com/a/adw/0877/5eabcb338dc604c09b28a4df5a49ad78x.jpg?impolicy=resize&amp;h=514&quot;); 
width: 1897px; position: relative; left: 0px; top: 0px; z-index: 998; opacity: 0; height: 514px; transition: opacity 750ms ease;" data-slick-index="0" aria-hidden="true" tabindex="-1" role="option" aria-describedby="slick-slide00">
```

Here is example code 2:

```
<div id="slide-7ae8b29ddc9e45d1a219beffe5793b2b"
class="html-slide slide slick-slide" 
data-label="March-Madness.jpg" data-link="" data-target="" 
data-promo-id="" data-slick-index="2" aria-hidden="true" tabindex="-1" role="option" 
aria-describedby="slick-slide02" 
style="width: 1897px; position: relative; left: -3794px; top: 0px; z-index: 998; opacity: 0; height: 514px; transition: opacity 750ms ease;">
    <div class="slide-background" 
    style="background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)), url(&quot;https://pictures.dealer.com/g/goodsonacuraofdallasadw/1747/13ed067a023df8ad412feea2c6eddec9x.jpg?impolicy=resize&amp;h=514&quot;); height: 514px;">
        <img src="https://pictures.dealer.com/g/goodsonacuraofdallasadw/1747/13ed067a023df8ad412feea2c6eddec9x.jpg?impolicy=resize&amp;h=514" class="placeholder-image pull-left">                                                                  </div>
```

I need to get the `style` element from both examples of code so I can get the background image url. The issue is that the first code has the `style` in the parent div and the second set of code has the `style` in the child div. How do I get those two `style` elements at the same time using Python and beautifulsoup?

Here is the code I have tried:

```
import bs4
from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
my_url = 'https://www.goodsonacura.com/'

uClient = uReq(my_url)
page_html = uClient.read()
uClient.close()

page_soup = soup(page_html, "html.parser")
banner_info = page_soup.findAll('div',{'class':['slide has-link', 'html-slide slide has-link']})
picture = [banner.get('style') for banner in banner_info]
```

This code gives me the correct `style` element for the first example code, but it gives me the wrong `style` element for the second example code.

Comment: What have you tried? Post the code in the question.

Comment: @KeyurPotdar I have updated the question to show the code i have so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add "slide-background" class in the `find_all` query. See the example below:-

```
banner_info = page_soup.find_all('div',{'class':['slide has-link', 'html-slide slide has-link', 'slide-background']})
```

It works for me. May this helps you.